# ListBox.Items.CopyTo() Method

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I want to copy the items of a listBox starting with specified index. If the index is started from 0, it does not give an error (System.IndexOutOfRangeException). If it is started from 1, it gives an error.

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(new string[] { "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee" });
object[] array = new object[listBox1.Items.Count];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(array, 0);
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(array, 1);
```

I'm trying to understand why the listBox1.Items.CopyTo() method is not working. If the starting index will not work for any index other than 0, why is there a 2nd parameter.

Comment: Look at what happens if you declare the array with _new object[listBox1.Items.Count+1]_ and probably you will understand the problem

Comment: The `arrayIndex` parameter of `ObjectCollection.CopyTo` method is the index in the target array, **not** in the ListBox items list. Since your array is of size 5 (like the ListBox items), if you copy to it starting from index 1 you'll get out of bounds with the last element.

Answer (score 2):

**The problem:**

As you can see in the [`ObjectCollection.CopyTo` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.copyto?view=netframework-4.6.1), the `arrayIndex` parameter is:

> The location within the destination array to copy the items from the
> collection to.

It is **not** the start index in the `ListBox` items list.
`CopyTo` will **always** copy all the elements from the `ListBox`.

Since your destination `array` is allocated with number of elements equal to the number of items in the list, you have to copy from index 0.
If you use e.g. 1, assigning the last element in the ListBox will cause an out-of-bounds exception because the array has only `n-1` elements starting from 1.

**Solutions (depending on what you want to achieve):**

If you need **all** the elements from the `ListBox` into the array starting from index 1 in the array, you need to allocate 1 extra element in it:

```
int startIdxInArray = 1; // This can be changed for a different offset
object[] array = new object[listBox1.Items.Count + startIdxInArray];
listBox1.Items.CopyTo(array, startIdxInArray);
```

If instead you would like to copy only **some** of the `ListBox` elements (starting from a given position in the list), you can convert the items to an array, and use [`Array.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.6.1). In this case you can decrease the number of elements allocated in the array.
The code below shows how to copy the list elements starting from the 2nd one (at index 1):

```
int startIdxInList = 1; // This can be changed for a different offset
object[] array = new object[listBox1.Items.Count - startIdxInList];
Array.Copy(listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray(), startIdxInList, array, 0, array.Length);
```